# How does one allow any customer to process any order in store on woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

From the frontend I want any customer to be able to view and change the status of any store order from "pending" to "complete". How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Allow your customers to change the status of any order?  That seems problematic :)

But you could use the [WC API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/v3.html#orders) to set order status.